# Map of activated brain regions for special feature extraction method

Tags: machine-learning, classification, neuroimaging

I have read the following paper: "Feature Extraction for fMRI-Based Human Brain Activity Recognition". The most useful point for me is the new method of extracting features from fMRI images. It introduces Covariance Selection based feature selection (in the end, eigenvectors of some expression are chosen as new features).

My problem is now how to compute a activation map of the brain for different tasks. I feed these new features into a classifier (e.g. SVM) and train the classifier (there are several tasks). Then I want to create a map of the activated regions in the brain for each task with the help of the information from the classifier. When the features are voxels this is easy (just using the weighting of the classifier).

Does somebody know how this could be done with these new feature extraction method?

Comment: I can't reach to the paper. Does feature extraction is something related with PCA? If that so you can transform your new features back to voxel space.

Comment: @yasin.yazici I have the paper as a pdf which I could send you. Feature extraction just means how to construct feature vectors from the images, e.g. taking each voxel as a feature. PCA is used for dimensionality reduction of the feature vectors. In the mentioned paper they propose a new way of reducing the dimensionality and my problem is that I don't know how to transform the new features back to the old features (voxels).

Comment: @yasin.yazici Is there also a back transformation for ICA and non-negative matrix factorization (i.e. transformation of the new features back to voxel space as you mentioned for PCA)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't use ICA before, so I can't give a detailed explanation. Here is a link on ICA http://sccn.ucsd.edu/~arno/indexica.html. Under the title 'ICA in N Dimensions' there is a simple demonstration for back transformation.